# Fastest way to compare strings in C

Tags: c, string, comparison, type-conversion

If I have a program that needs to compare a lot of strings, what's the best way to do it such that run time is at a minimum?

Comment: I have used strcmp but it seems to take too long. Maybe I can convert them to integers and then compare ?

Comment: what do you mean by compare a lot of strings? Sort them in order or what?

Comment: If you are literally just doing one-off comparisons of strings, then you can't do much better then `strcmp`.  In more complex scenarios, you could use a hash-table, or a trie, or some other lookup-based scheme.

Comment: You'll have to go much further in describing your problem to hope to get a good answer. Are you trying to find the two identical strings in ten million inputs? Or are you trying to find which of ten million inputs is identical to a single given "target" string? Or will the first ten million characters of each string be identical? You've given us nearly nothing to work with.

Comment: If you do that then you may have different strings with the same value, unlikely but possible.

Comment: Have you tried using `strcmp()`?

Comment: Depending on your expected input, try shortcuts to rule out non-identical strings.  For example, compare the first character in each of the two strings (`==`); if they're not equal, you can skip the call to `strcmp()`.

Comment: @Alex: that may avoid function call overhead (assuming that strcmp()` isn't inlined), but comparing the first character of each string in some fashion is going to be the first thing that `strcmp()` does, too.  I suspect the OP is going to need an algorithmic solution that depends on the particular needs and behavior of his application, not some tweaks on the brute force technique. However, unless the OP updates the question to describe what those needs and behaviors are, there's not much that can be answered here. Of course, I'm just guessing...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`strcmp()` - compare two strings.

```
const char *s1, *s2;
```

are the strings to be compared.

```
int i;
i = strcmp( s1, s2 );
```

gives the results of the comparison. `i` is zero if the strings are identical. `i` is positive if string `s1` is greater than string `s2`, and is negative if string `s2` is greater than string `s1`. Comparisons of "greater than" and "less than" are made according to the ASCII collating sequence.

`strcmp()` compares the string `s1` to the string `s2`. Both strings must be terminated by the usual '`\0'` character.

---

`strncmp()`

```
const char *s1, *s2;
```

are the strings to be compared.

```
size_t N;
```

gives the number of characters to be examined.

```
int i;
i = strncmp( s1, s2, N );
```

gives the results of the comparison. `i` is zero if the first `N` characters of the strings are identical. `i` is positive if string "s1" is greater than string `s2`, and is negative if string "s2" is greater than string `s1`. Comparisons of "greater than" and "less than" are made according to the ASCII collating sequence.

`strncmp()` compares the first N characters of the string `s1` to the first `N` characters of the string `s2`. If one or both of the strings is shorter than `N` characters (i.e. if `strncmp()` encounters a '`\0'`), comparisons will stop at that point. Thus `N` represents the maximum number of characters to be examined, not the exact number. (Note that if `N` is zero, `strncmp()` will always return zero -- no characters are checked, so no differences are found.)

---

```
memcmp()
const void *s1, *s2;
```

are the strings to be compared. 
size_t N;

gives the number of characters to be examined.

```
int i;
i = memcmp( s1, s2, N );
```

gives the results of the comparison. `i` is zero if the first `N` characters of the strings are identical. `i` is positive if string "s1" is greater than string `s2`, and is negative if string `s2` is greater than string `s1`. Comparisons of "greater than" and "less than" are made according to the ASCII collating sequence.

`memcmp()` compares the first `N` characters of the string "s1" to the first N characters of the string `s2`.

Unlike the function `strncmp()`, `memcmp()` does not check for a `'\0'` terminating either string. Thus it examines a full `N` characters, even if the strings are not actually that long.

---

```
wmemcmp()
int wmemcmp(const wchar_t *a1, const wchar_t *a2, size_t size);
```

The function `wmemcmp()` compares the size wide characters beginning at a1 against the size wide characters beginning at a2. The value returned is smaller than or larger than zero depending on whether the first differing wide character is a1 is smaller or larger than the corresponding character in a2.

If the contents of the two blocks are equal, `wmemcmp()` returns 0.

On arbitrary arrays, the `memcmp()` function is mostly useful for testing equality. It usually isn't meaningful to do byte-wise ordering comparisons on arrays of things other than bytes. For example, a byte-wise comparison on the bytes that make up floating-point numbers isn't likely to tell you anything about the relationship between the values of the floating-point numbers.

---

```
wcscmp()
int wcscmp(const wchar_t *ws1, const wchar_t *ws2);
```

The wcscmp function compares the wide character string ws1 against ws2. The value returned is smaller than or larger than zero depending on whether the first differing wide character is ws1 is smaller or larger than the corresponding character in ws2.

If the two strings are equal, `wcscmp()` returns 0.

A consequence of the ordering used by `wcscmp()` is that if ws1 is an initial substring of `ws2`, then ws1 is considered to be “less than” ws2.

`wcscmp()` does not take sorting conventions of the language the strings are written in into account. To get that one has to use `wcscoll`.

---

```
wcscasecmp()
int wcscasecmp(const wchar_t *ws1, const wchar_T *ws2)
```

This function is like `wcscmp()`, except that differences in case are ignored. How uppercase and lowercase characters are related is determined by the currently selected locale. In the standard "C" locale the characters Ä and ä do not match but in a locale which regards these characters as parts of the alphabet they do match.

---

```
strcmpi()

int strcmpi(const char *string1, const char *string2);
```

`strcmpi()` compares `string1` and `string2` without sensitivity to case. **All alphabetic characters in the two arguments string1 and string2 are converted to lowercase before the comparison**.

The function operates on null-ended strings. The string arguments to the function are expected to contain a null character `'\0'` marking the end of the string.

`strcmpi()` returns a value indicating the relationship between the two strings , as follows

Less than 0 `string1` less than `string2`

0 `string1` equivalent to string2

Greater than 0 `string1` greater than `string2`.

---

```
strcasecmp()
int strcasecmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

This function is like `strcmp()`, except that differences in case are ignored. How uppercase and lowercase characters are related is determined by the currently selected locale. In the standard "C" locale the characters Ä and ä do not match but in a locale which regards these characters as parts of the alphabet they do match.

---

```
strncasecmp()
int strncasecmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n);
```

This function is like `strncmp()`, except that differences in case are ignored. Like `strcasecmp()`, it is locale dependent how uppercase and lowercase characters are related.

---

*Which approach is best is certainly dependent upon your requirements.*

Answer (score 5):

You can use `strcmp( string1,string2);`

If they are arrays of strings: `strcmp(string1[i], string2[j]);`

It will return a number:

- If it's 0, then they are the same.
- If it's greater than 0, string one is alphabetically larger than the second.
- If it's smaller than 0, string one is alphabetically smaller than the second.

Comment: Is there any other method thats faster ?

Comment: not that i know of.

Maybe you can create your own function.

pass in both strings and then compare each character of the char array.

Comment: There's nearly no chance that a hand-written `strcmp()` replacement will be faster -- the built-in one will use as many clever tricks as it can to compare as many bytes in aligned reads as possible.

Comment: @Oli: `strcpm()` is the fast version of `strcmp()`.  Use it judiciously, like when your boss wants a quick fix that'll make you look like a hero.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth WoooW i did not know what you guys were even talking about until I reviewed it lol. Sorry about that